# Atom Flatpak using sandboxed runtimes and executables in package settings

Tags: php, executable, flatpak, atom

I'm using the flatpak version of Atom. I want to install a linting package for PHP, so that code errors are easier to spot. However it requires access to the php binary.

Now since this is a Flatpak, it's sandboxed so no chance of me giving it proper access to the `/usr/bin` directory any time soon, but I discovered I could use a Flatpak runtime of PHP 7.4 called `org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.php74`, which should provide me with what I need.

The only question that's left for me is how do I pass this to the package? The setting I'm provided with is a path text field, where I'd normally pass it the `/usr/bin/php` path, but how do I invoke the flatpak equivalent to that?

Addendum: As partially stated in one of the comments, I could use the debian package and have atom be able to directly use the binary in the root directories, but I'm insistent on using the flatpak, as the sandboxing is a feature that I actually want to maintain

Comment: Workaround: Use the .deb package for atom. Alternatively, ask the flatpak maintainer for support.

Comment: I was considering it, but the deb package version is behind on version compared to the flatpak, and I actually like the fact that things are sadboxed. I've figured out how to make the Godot Engine flatpak use the Atom flatpak as an external editor for game dev, now I want to finish setting up my web dev environment.